Strictly speaking, are unsigned suffixes ever required for literals in any Bitwise operation?
Strictly speaking, according to the C standard, are unsigned suffixes ever required for numeric literals in any Bitwise operation (to avoid UB)? Particularly around shifts, I think it is undefined behaviour when involving signed numbers and my understanding is that literals are signed but I am not sure. I.e.
4 << x; // or is 4U << x required?
4 >> x;
4 & x;
4 | x;
// etc. for all bit ops

x << 4;
x >> 4;
// etc.

where 4 is a placeholder for any literal.
I know that most compilers would not care either way, I am just interested in what the spec says.

4 << x will cause UB for some (not all) values of x. 4U << x will also cause UB for some (not all) values of x. It is up to you to not to supply such values in either case.

No, unsigned suffixed aren't strictly required using bitwise operators, that's because the ANSI C standard says at chapter 2.9 that bitwise operators must be applied to signed or unsigned integer operands (char, short, int and long).
However, especially in shifts, where the amount of bits to shift cannot be a negative number, would a bit more correct to specify it anyway.

Obviously you'll also want the suffix when the literal won't fit into an integer.

@tofro why? If the literal doesn't fit in an int, a larget integer type will automatically be chosen. Did you mean "if the result of shifting" doesn't fit?

No version of the C standard, from the 1990 ANSI C standard to the 2023 ISO C standard, has a chapter 2.9, section 2.9, or clause 2.9. Perhaps you are referring to The C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie, which covers bitwise operators in section 2.9 in both editions. The second edition has “ANSI C” stamped in red on the cover, but that is a marketing ploy indicating the book was updated to address the ANSI C standard. It does not indicate the book is the ANSI C standard.

The C standard has no prohibition on using an integer literal (which the standard calls a “constant”) without an unsigned-suffix. However, getting the desired result may require a suffix.
Most simply, consider 1 << n where n is 31 and int is 32 bits. Then 1 << n is not defined by the C standard, because 231 is not representable in int, but 1u << n is defined.

I see, thanks. I guess I asked the wrong question then, what I meant to ask was actually "excluding the case where the number is not representable, for which bitwise operations will the result differ when using an unsigned vs signed literal".
